# Dynamically allocate a string matrix in C

Tags: c, matrix, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to read a map from a text file and create a string array according to the number of rows and columns in the map. Every cell in the grid is a 2 character string.

For instance,

```
**--**--**--
--**--**--**
```

should create a 2*6 matrix. The number of rows and columns are ROWS and COLS respectively. I used

```
char ***map = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char *));
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) 
{
    map[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(char) *  2);
}
```

But when I try to use a `map[x][y]`, it will segfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char ***map;` could be interpreted as an "Array of arrays of strings", so the inner array actually contains char pointers. Therefore, your loop needs to look like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
    int j;

    map[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(char*));
    for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++) map[i][j] = malloc(3 * sizeof(char)); // 3 chars because a string has to be terminated by \0
}
```

Alternatively, you could declare map as `char **map`, then your initialization code would work, but then you'd need to use `map[i][j]` and `map[i][j+1]` to access the elements of the individual cells.

Comment: Tried this one, and it doesn't segfault now, but now it looks like the array is empty, or for some reason it's not printing anything. Doesn't seem to be the way I read the file into the array. http://pastebin.com/8Uu4fNJf

Comment: Uh, filled the array manually and it looks like it's printing now. Well, I guess I should take care of the reading issue.

Comment: About the reading issue: I used fgets to count the number of rows and columns in the map, and of course, it went until the EOF. So I had to restart the pointer position by closing and reopening the file, but I think there should be a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @user1002327 That's what `fseek` (or in your special case, `rewind`) is for.

Answer (score 2):

It could look like this:

```
int i, j, ROWS = 2, COLS = 6;
char ***map = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char **));
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
{
   map[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(char*));
   for (j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
      map[i][j] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
}
```

Note that 2 `char`s allow you to store these characters, but it could cause you some troubles if you are going to work with them as a string (`printf("%s`, `strcpy` ...). In that case I would rather allocate memory for 3 `char`s so that terminating character can be stored as well.

Also note that you should clean this memory once it is allocated and cleaning should be done in reverse order according to allocation. It could look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
{
   for (j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
      free(map[i][j]);
   free(map[i]);
}
free(map);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you know that each string is only 2 characters, you don't necessarily need the 3rd character.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: Yes, 2 characters would be enough for storing them. But what if he wants to print them? He doesn't need to write own function for printing if terminating character is there...

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII : Anyway, that's a good point. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be

```
char ***map = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char**));
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) 
{
   map[i] = malloc(COLS * sizeof(char*));
   for (int j=0; i<COLS; ++j)
      map[i][j] = malloc(3*sizeof(char);
}
```

Edit: As pointed out in another answer and a comment, should be 3 not 2 malloc'ed chars.

Comment: But if you know in advance that each entry is 2 characters, you might just want to make it a matrix of `unsigned short`s and reinterpret where necessary, that might be less annoying overall.

Comment: It may be better to `malloc` three characters, two for the string characters and one for the null terminator character.

Comment: @user1002327 Where? And try it with 3 instead of 2 in the last line (see edit above).

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2D array, way do you declare `map` as `char***`? Change it to `char**`.

(If I misunderstoop, and you want 2D array of `char*`, you should change the allocation, to use `sizeof(char**)` and `sizeof(char*)`, and allocate memory to the string separately.)

Edit: If you know the size of the map when you declare it, make it `char map[ROWS][COLS][2];`
If you don't (or you want to simply pass it to another functions), you can declare it as `char (**map)[2]`, and keep your allocations as they are.

(Change the `2` to `3` if you want to terminate them by `\0` (To print it, for example))

Comment: It's a 2D array of strings, so I added the extra *. I'll see what happens with `char**`.

Comment: Don't forget to allocate the memory to the string!

Comment: Sizeof `char **` and sizeof `char *` is equivalent throughout a system. The size of one pointer type is always the same as another.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Generaly, 2 pointer types may have different size. Is there something special in such cases?

Comment: @asaelr no, what I mean is that the address of a block of memory is always the same size (generally 32 bit on 32 bit systems, and 64 bit on 64 bit systems). What the address actually points to, however, is another story.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Well, you are wrong. `void*` is the widest pointer, but the standard says almost nothing about the size of other pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The first line should be:

```
char **map = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char *));
```

As a rule of thumb, add one `*` to the return type of malloc(). If you allocate an array of five ints with `malloc(5 * sizeof(int))` then you would get back an `int *`.

Or, you can think of each `*` as adding a dimension—`char *` is a 1-D array of characters, and `char **` is a 2-D array.